# Probability calculation chance

Tags: probability, functions

I need to develop an application that is based on a mathematical algorithm, but I do not which mathematical formula should I use. Basically I want to find out what is the probability of entering in a highschools given my overall grade and knowing the last admission grade. How do I compute my chance of entering in that highschool. If someone could give me some hints or ideas on how to approach this problem I would be really grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is insufficient information to do what you want.  Knowing a single grade that was admitted doesn't tell you anything about the percentage of people with other grades that were admitted.  (There are, obviously, other factors to admission besides grades.)

If you knew the grades of all the applicants, as well as which ones were admitted, that would allow you to estimate your probability of admission, but that would likely be based on some kind of curve fit or statistical approach.

Comment: If I knew the last grade for admission and the first grade for admission would I be able to compute the probability using some kind of curve or function? What kind of curve could I use ?

Comment: @blaa: No, because it could be any curve.  It would be like telling you two points on a curve, and asking you what the function was that connected those two points.  There's way too little information.  It would be interesting, statistically, if schools habitually end up following some consistent kind of curve, but (a) I don't know if that's true and if so, what curve it would be; and (b) that wouldn't necessarily follow for your case, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure you've given enough parameters, but here's a useful formula: $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

Where $P(A|B)$ denotes the probability of $A$ occurring, given that $B$ has occurred and $P(A\cap B)$ denotes the probability of both $A$ and $B$ occurring. In this case, $A$ would be the event that you enter the high school, and $B$ would be your overall grade. I suppose that $P(A)$ would then depend somehow on the last admission grade for that school.